# Collect POST data, process it and POST that data to an external URL

Tags: django, django-views

I'm trying to implement a data processing module.

The scenario is,

1. First a user will POST some data.
2. User POSTed data needs to be processed and some more info needs to be added here
3. This processed POST data should be sent to an external URL with out user intervention.

The external URL will accept only POST requests.

Please suggest me a way to send this POST data to external URL.

**Update**

As suggested, I started using requests.

In the view that i collected the initial POST data, I'm compiling another data object with the user posted data (after processing) and adding some more data to the object and doing the post request as bellow

```
req = requests.post(post_url, data=post_obj)
```

the status_code returned is 200
But the data(post_obj) doesn't seem to be sent to the post_url. The post_url is prompting that it did not receive the POST data.

when I checked the req object,

req.request.data seems to have the post_obj information and req.request.url has the post_url

req.url has the redirect_url which is prompting that the post_url didn't receive any data.

My question is,

How to actually POST the data?
what is the object that needs to be returned in the view?

If the way I'm POSTing the data (requests.post method) is wrong. Please suggest me the appropriate way.

Note: After POSTing the data to the post_url, it will be redirected to a different page.

Comment: You might want to make that another question. Otherwise, please post more code.

Comment: I think you need to do `data = urllib.urlencode(post_obj)` to encode the object correctly for the POST request

Answer (score 2):

Use [Urllib2](http://docs.python.org/library/urllib2.html), [mechanise](http://wwwsearch.sourceforge.net/mechanize/) or [requests](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/requests) (who all use pythons built in urllib2 and httplib) or [pycurl](http://pycurl.sourceforge.net/) (which uses libcurl) to do the posts to the external resource.

Requests is the easiest to work with, mechanize is great for filling out forms and programming like a browser, urllib2 is the underlying library so it's also important to know and pycurl is (imo) a last resort due to not being particularly maintained

You should consider using a queue to handle the server->third party step and then asynchronously report to the user that the task has completed, otherwise you face potentially timing your connections out if your 3rd party app takes to long to respond.

Comment: from your response, mechanize fits my bill well... will give this a try now.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the standard library [urllib2](http://docs.python.org/library/urllib2.html) to do the 2nd POST.

I've also heard good things about the [requests library](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/requests), which should be easier to use than urllib2.

Comment: Looks like the solution I'm looking for. Thank you very much.